# split String to list by two words - python

Tags: python, list, split

I am trying to split a String into a list every time the word '::' or 'episode' appear. I want to split the list every time one of those words appears but I can only give one word to the method 'split()'.

Comment: can you provide an example of the string you are working with, and what is the output you want??

Comment: also what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will help

```
import re
delimiters = "::", "episode"
example = "hello:: this episode is my favourite"
regexPattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, delimiters))
print(re.split(regexPattern, example))
```